# Encrypting AppSettings in file external to Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I currently use this method to encrypt the AppSettings section of my application's web.config file: `aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "appSettings" -site "MySite" -app "/"`

But now I have moved some settings out to another file using the element

```
<appSettings file="IndividualAppSettings.config" >
```

I can still encrypt the app setting in the web.config, but is there any way to encrypt the content of the additional IndividualAppSettings.config file?

Comment: All of the resources I'm finding are about encrypting the web.config file itself... not the external file referenced by the web.config.

Comment: may I ask just out of curiosity ..why are you using 2 separate .config files..?

Comment: I'm doing it this way so I can deploy the web.config full of library references to hundreds of sites without having to edit each site's web.config. Each web.config would be identical, but each appsettings.config would be site specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We do this all the time as we use external files for each of our environments.

First your `appSettings` element needs to look like this:

```
<appSettings configSource="IndividualAppSettings.config" />
```

Next, we call the encryption from the cmdline using:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -prov "{0}" -site {1} -app "/"
```

where:

- `{0}` is the name of your encryption provider specified in the web.config.
- `{1}` is the Id of your site in IIS

Comment: The "File" element allows elements in the section to be inherited and overridden, which is a huge plus. The configSource does not allow that; the section must be empty. But if this is the only way, that is what I'll have to do.

Comment: got it - I am only familiar with encrypting the *entire* appSettings section.