# Encrypting partial external AppSettings config

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, web-config

Note that **I am aware of this question**:
[Encrypting AppSettings in file external to Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784730/encrypting-appsettings-in-file-external-to-web-config)

And this is NOT a dupe.  That question has an answer allowing the encryption of an external appSettings config file *only if* appSettings is linked using the `configSource` attribute.  I want to use the `file` attribute.  So, I have something like this in my Web.config:

```
<appSettings file="ExternalSettings.config">
    <add key="InternalSetting" value="Test123" />
</appSettings>
```

... and an ExternalSettings.config file in the same directory with its own `appSettings` section.  When I run my web app, the two `appSettings` contents are merged together.  However, if I try to just encrypt my ExternalSettings.config file like this:

```
var webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/ExternalSettings.config");
ConfigurationSection section = webConfig.GetSection("appSettings");
if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected) {
    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
    webConfig.Save();
}
```

I get a `ConfigurationErrorsException` saying

> "A configuration file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object."

(by the way, this code works fine for encrypting an `appSettings` section that is just in Web.config)

Is there any way of encrypting the settings in my ExternalSettings.config file, but leaving the Web.Config ones unencrypted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. You can use the following code to encrypt the appSettings of a configuration file.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "ExternalSettings.config";
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection section = configuration.AppSettings;
if (section != null && section.SectionInformation.IsProtected == false)
{
    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
    configuration.Save();
}
```

However, this expects a valid configuration file and not an appSettings snippet. So you need to enclose the appSettings in a configuation element before running

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add....
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This will turn the file into something like

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
      <CipherData>        <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAADx8S4qABcUakeKay9R2hvgQAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAAyNc22wc25O41jcxXcAD8MAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAIRVbMW6KjGTFu0O8ZC1YGqIAAAAO6L8wKbLrXX4WSh+HBMPMzR1ypiWMGfC/tFS0swDwYCbBYZEXM1WU9vf3XTA/zftK+6yYLDXQ348Easx0f/a+IaZlsUvtsCJ9LSBSVM/++7JZkKrq2Zah2aQjqjn3G80XqCNc+OCNiFRhmb2ng8m3ioxC/CeOC9mVBX2qz97PIend+u4CLVBIhQAAAAsoiPgaQd9sRcFjsXQuYtTWY+qgw==</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then remove the configuration start and end elements once encrypted and the runtime will pick up the values as before when unencrypted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is related to mixing keys from main and external configurations. The following definition works fine for me:

```
<appSettings file="Configuration\AppSettings.config" />
```

Something in external file

```
<appSettings>
    <!--Your configuration keys-->
</appSettings>
```

External section correctly encrypt/decrypt